# How many times can I memory map the same file in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, embedded

I'm working in an embedded linux system that allows me to access hardware peripherals through `/dev/mem`. I'd like to memory map different segments of this file (potentially a few hundred different mmaps). This leads me to the question:

Given enough address space, is there a limit in Linux to the number of times I can memory map different parts of the same file?

Comment: For `mmap` of peripherals into userspace, I don't think you want to use `/dev/mem`. See my answer: [Memcpy performance on /dev/mem outside kernel ram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37399307/5382650)

Comment: Why treat them as memory mapped files?  Seems like overkill.  In all the embedded systems I worked on, the hardware was accessed via pointer.  You assign the pointer to the H/W register, then dereference the pointer.  Simple.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It sounds like your embeded systems had direct memory access, wheras OP seems to maybe be in user mode with virtual memory?