# Is Dynamic Linker part of Kernel or GCC Library on Linux Systems?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-linking

Is Dynamic Linker (aka Program Interpreter, Link Loader) part of Kernel or GCC  Library ?

**UPDATE** (28-08-16):

I have found that the default path for *dynamic linker* that every binary (i.e linked against a shared library) uses `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is a link to the shared library `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so` which is the actual dynamic linker.

And It is part of `libc6 (2.23-0ubuntu3)` package viz. [GNU C Library: Shared libraries](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libc6/filelist) in ubuntu for AMD64 architectures.

My actual question was

what would happen to all the applications that are dynamically linked (all,now a days), if this helper program (**ld-2.23.so**) doesn't exist ?

And answer to that is " no application would run, even the shell program ".  I've tried it on virutal machine.

Comment: `ld.so` is not a part of the kernel, but is loaded by it.

Comment: It's actually part of GNU libc on Linux; see http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~dww4s/articles/ld_linux.html

Comment: @nephtes That link doesn't work; 403 error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In an ELF executable, this is referred to as the "ELF interpreter". On linux (e.g.) this is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

This is *not* part of the kernel and [generally] with `glibc` et. al.

When the kernel executes an ELF executable, it must map the executable into userspace memory. It then looks inside for a special sub-section known as `INTERP` [which contains a string that is the full path].

The kernel then maps the interpreter into userspace memory and transfers control to it. Then, the interpreter does the necessary linking/loading and starts the program.

Because `ELF` stands for "extensible linker format", this allows many different sub-sections with the ELF file.

Rather than burdening the kernel with having to know about all the myriad of extensions, the ELF interpreter that is paired with the file knows.

Although usually only one format is used on a given system, there can be several different variants of ELF files on a system, each with its own ELF interpreter.

This would allow [say] a BSD ELF file to be run on a linux system [with other adjustments/support] because the ELF file would point to the BSD ELF interpreter rather than the linux one.

---

**UPDATE:**

> every process(vlc player, chrome) had the shared library ld.so as part of their address space.

Yes. I assume you're looking at `/proc/<pid>/maps`. These are *mappings* (e.g. like using `mmap`) to the files. That is somewhat different than "loading", which can imply [symbol] *linking*.

> So primarily loader after loading the executable(code & data) onto memory , It loads& maps dynamic linker (.so) to its address space

The best way to understand this is to rephrase what you just said:

*So primarily **the kernel** after **mapping** the executable(code & data) onto memory, **the kernel** maps dynamic linker (.so) to **the program** address space*

That is essentially correct. The kernel also maps other things, such as the `bss` segment and the stack. It then "pushes" `argc`, `argv`, and `envp` [the space for environment variables] onto the stack.

Then, having determined the start address of `ld.so` [by reading a special section of the file], it sets that as the resume address and starts the thread.

Up until now, it has been the kernel doing things. The kernel does little to no symbol *linking*.

Now, `ld.so` takes over ...

> which further Loads shared Libraries , map & resolve references to libraries. It then calls entry function (_start)

Because the original executable (e.g. `vlc`) has been mapped into memory, `ld.so` can examine it for the list of shared libraries that it needs. It *maps* these into memory, but does *not* necessarily *link* the symbols right away.

Mapping is easy and quick--just an `mmap` call.

The start address of the executable [*not* to be confused with the start address of `ld.so`], is taken from a special section of the ELF executable. Although, the symbol associated with this start address has been traditionally called `_start`, it could actually be named anything (e.g. `__my_start`) as it is what is in the section data that determines the start address and *not* address of the symbol `_start`

Linking symbol references to symbol definitions is a time consuming process. So, this is deferred until the symbol is actually used. That is, if a program has references to `printf`, the linker doesn't actually try to link in `printf` until the first time the program actually *calls* `printf`

This is sometimes called "link-on-demand" or "on-demand-linking". See my answer here: [Which segments are affected by a copy-on-write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047977/which-segments-are-affected-by-a-copy-on-write/37060802#37060802) for a more detailed explanation of that and what actually happens when an executable is mapped into userspace.

If you're interested, you could do `ldd /usr/bin/vlc` to get a list of the shared libraries it uses. If you looked at the output of `readelf -a /usr/bin/vlc`, you'll see these same shared libraries. Also, you'd get the full path of the ELF interpreter and could do `readelf -a <full_path_to_interpreter>` and note some of the differences. You could repeat the process for any `.so` files that `vlc` wanted.

Combining all that with `/proc/<pid>maps` et. al. might help with your understanding.

Comment: @criag . As I have noticed , every process(vlc player, chrome) had the shared library **ld.so** as part of their address space. So primarily loader after loading the executable(code & data) onto memory , It loads& maps **dynamic linker (.so)** to its address space which further Loads shared Libraries , map & resolve references to libraries. It then calls entry function (_start) . Is this correct ?

Comment: @craig. I have used the program **_ldd_** already which prints the shared dependencies .

Comment: I would have guessed that you were familiar with `ldd`, I mentioned it [and other things] to produce a complete answer. Actually, `ldd` is a shell script. It simply sets the environment variable `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS` and then does an `exec` of `/usr/bin/vlc`. The ELF interpreter [for `vlc`] notices this variable and does the printing (and terminates rather than full execution). `ld.so` can't use program arguments, so to provide it with options, environment variables are set. The manpage has a fairly complete list (e.g. `man ld.so`)

Comment: @CraigEstey , ok, i got it now.