# Why shared library is unloaded while another program still uses it?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

For what I understand, if there are more than one program using a shared library, the shared library won't get unloaded untill all program finishes.

I am reading *The Linux Programming Interface*:

> #### 42.4 Initialization and Finalization Functions   It is possible to define one or more functions that are executed automatically when a
>
> shared library is loaded and unloaded. This allows us to perform
> initialization and finalization actions when working with shared
> libraries. Initialization and finalization functions are executed
> regardless of whether the library is loaded automatically or loaded
> explicitly using the `dlopen` interface (Section 42.1).
>
> Initialization and finalization functions are defined using the gcc
> constructor and destructor attributes. Each function that is to be
> executed when the library is loaded should be defined as follows:
>
> ```
> void __attribute__ ((constructor)) some_name_load(void)
> {
>  /* Initialization code */
> }
> ```
>
> Unload functions are similarly defined:
>
> ```
> void __attribute__ ((destructor)) some_name_unload(void)
> {
>  /* Finalization code */
> } The function names `some_name_load()` and `some_name_unload()` can be replaced by any desired names. ....
> ```

---

Then I wrote 3 files to test:

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((constructor)) call_me_when_load(void){
    printf("Loading....\n");
}
void __attribute__((destructor)) call_me_when_unload(void){
    printf("Unloading...\n");
}
int xyz(int a ){
    return a + 3;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int xyz(int);
    int b;
    for(int i = 0;i < 1; i++){
         b = xyz(i);
             printf("xyz(i) is: %d\n", b);
    }
}
```

main_while_sleep.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int xyz(int);
    int b;
    for(int i = 0;i < 10; i++){
         b = xyz(i);
             sleep(1);
             printf("xyz(i) is: %d\n", b);
    }
}
```

Then I compile a shared library and 2 executables:

```
gcc -g -Wall -fPIC -shared -o libdemo.so foo.c
gcc -g -Wall -o main main.c libdemo.so
gcc -g -Wall -o main_while_sleep main_while_sleep.c libdemo.so
```

finally run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main_while_sleep` in a shell and run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main` in another:

`main_while_sleep` output:

```
Loading....
xyz(i) is: 3
xyz(i) is: 4
xyz(i) is: 5
xyz(i) is: 6
xyz(i) is: 7
xyz(i) is: 8
xyz(i) is: 9
xyz(i) is: 10
xyz(i) is: 11
xyz(i) is: 12
Unloading...
```

`main` output:

```
Loading....
xyz(i) is: 3
Unloading...
```

---

**My question is**, while `main_while_sleep` is not finished, why `Unloading` is printed in `main`, which indicates the shared library has been unloaded? The shared library shouldn't be unloaded yet, `main_while_sleep` is still running!

Do I get something wrong?

Comment: The initialization and finalization actions are per process.  The system won't unload the library completely while a process is using it, but a process may unload the library, or terminate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't get it. :( Could you elaborate?

Comment: The library is loaded per process, not per system. Every process has its own separate instance of loaded library. Let's say a copy.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ok I see. 1 copy per process, so 10 copies for 10 processes, but only 1 copy in physical memory, do I get this right?

Comment: If what I say above is correct, is there anyway I can observe the "shared library is not unloaded till all programs using it terminate"  behaviour in physical memory? I mean, I would like to see when `main` is terminated while `main_while_sleep`, the system-wide **1 copy** is still there.

Comment: @Rick yes, it is like each process has its own copy, but with less physical memory.

Comment: `do I get this right?` Yes, "as-if". `I can observe the "shared library is not unloaded till all programs using it terminate" behaviour in physical memory?` I do not know what you mean by "observe". `lsof` gives you for example all open files on the system.

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can probably deduce from information in the `/proc` file system which shared libraries are loaded — though you'll quite likely need elevated privileges (`root` privileges) to do so.  Otherwise, the may be specialized system calls to tell you what's loaded — you'll need to scrutinize the manual (section 2, system calls).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, while main_while_sleep is not finished, why Unloading is printed in main, which indicates the shared library has been unloaded? The shared library shouldn't be unloaded yet, main_while_sleep is still running!

You are confusing/conflating initialization/deinitialization with load/unload.

A constructor is an *initialization* function that is called *after* a shared library has been *mapped* into a given process's memory.

It does not affect any other process (which is in a separate, per-process address space).

Likewise, the mapping (or unmapping) of a shared library in a given process does *not* affect any other process.

When a process maps a library, nothing is "loaded". When the process tries to access a memory page that is part of the shared library, it receives a page fault and the given page is mapped, the page is marked resident, and the faulting instruction is restarted.

There is much more detail in my answers:

1. [How does mmap improve file reading speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172740/how-does-mmap-improve-file-reading-speed/37173063#37173063)
2. [Which segments are affected by a copy-on-write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047977/which-segments-are-affected-by-a-copy-on-write/37060802#37060802)
3. [read line by line in the most efficient way *platform specific*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616284/read-line-by-line-in-the-most-efficient-way-platform-specific/33620968#33620968)
4. [Is Dynamic Linker part of Kernel or GCC Library on Linux Systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857741/is-dynamic-linker-part-of-kernel-or-gcc-library-on-linux-systems/38857878#38857878)
5. [Malloc is using 10x the amount of memory necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753265/malloc-is-using-10x-the-amount-of-memory-necessary/39761864#39761864)